# read cell number formatting in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to **READ** a cell's **number format** using **openpyxl**. More specifically, I want to check if a cell is formatted as '**Percent**' using openpyxl? Is this possible?

I've reviewed the documentation but I couldn't find an answer.

Note:
1. I am not interested is the cell is a unicode, string, number. I want to know the cell 
2. I don't want to set number formatting instead of want to read

Comment: `cell.number_format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. My script I just made to test looks like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("test.xlsx") # or whatever book
ws = wb["Sheet1"] # or whatever sheet

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.style)
```

With a sample output of:

```
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Percent
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
```

Where it is clear I formatted a single cell to be a `Percent`

Comment: @Boosted_d16 No problem! To figure it out I just used a useful trick of `print(dir(cell))` to see what methods were available, and tried a couple like `style` and `style_id` to figure out what worked. Something to consider in the future!